# How can i set an inline style margin according to a condition?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

So I have my layout from Ant design and on the profile page theres one div at the top which has user's info.

Under it, there are many divs (one for each post), essentially mapping a post array into post divs.
Problem is, ive struggled with centring them to the middle of the page but after messing around with flex, i thought i did a good job in the end. It looked perfect at first when the user has no posts underneath the profile div. The moment there's posts, the profile div goes to the left alot for some goddamn reason.

The posts are perfectly centered like i want them but my problem is with the profile div. To fix it, i did a `margin-left` on the it. This makes it look perfect. But not so fast. Now when theres no posts, its awfully to the right cuz it was perfectly centered before the `margin-left`

So is there any way i can pass in a condition to say `if posts.length === 0`, and set the margin-left accordingly?

Losing my head.

`Layout.js` code:

```
<Content style={{ padding: '0 50px' }}>
       <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: '16px 0' }}>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>Network</Breadcrumb.Item>
       </Breadcrumb>
       <div className="site-layout-content" style={{ background: "#fff ", padding: 24, minHeight: 280, display:"flex", alignItems:"center", flexDirection: "column"}}>
                {children}
       </div>
</Content>
```

`UserProfile.js` code :

```
<div>
       <div className="site-card-wrapper"  style={{display: "inline-block",marginBottom:20, width: 500, marginLeft:355}}>
             <Row gutter={16} type="flex" style={{justifyContent: "center", }}>
             <Col span={16}>
                 <Card title={user.username} bordered={true} style={{border: "1px solid #cccccc",}}>
                     <div style={{display:"flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
                         <CardContent>Followers: {user.followers === undefined ? "0" : user.followers.length}</CardContent>
                         <CardContent>Following: {user.following === undefined ? "0" : user.following.length}</CardContent>
                     </div>
                 </Card>
             </Col>
             </Row>
         </div>
         
         {
              (userPosts.length > 0) ?
              <Heading>Posts</Heading> :
              <Heading>No posts yet</Heading>
         }    

         {
             userPosts.map(post => {
                 return <SinglePost key={post.id} post={post} />
             })
         }
            
</div>
```

`SinglePost.js` code (simplified):

```
<div className="site-card-wrapper" style={{marginBottom:20, width: 1200,}}>
            <Row gutter={16} type="flex" style={{justifyContent: "center"}}>
            <Col span={16} >
                <Card title={user.username} bordered={true} style={{border: "1px solid #cccccc"}}>
                    <div style={{fontSize: 18, marginTop: -10, whiteSpace: "pre-line"}}> 
                        {post.content}
                    </div>
    
                    <Likes>{likes} Likes</Likes>
                </Card>
            </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div className="site-card-wrapper"
     style={
           {display: "inline-block",
            marginBottom:20,
            width: 500,
            marginLeft:posts.length === 0 ? 0 : 355
           }}>
```

use above conditional statement to handle run time marginLeft

Comment: omg. I tried everything of that sort and for some reason and it wasnt working. Life saver thank you